# How Post all selected values of dropdown to controller?

Tags: html

```
                <a class='btn btn-primary' href='http://localhost/index.php/Welcome/delete_pro/".$row->pid."'>DELETE</a>
```

that pid is not pass in the URL.

Comment: Please describe your problem, like what all frameworks you are using along with HTML

Comment: If this is HTML code then it won't work because HTML does not have variables.

if this is PHP code, and you have something like (`echo "<a class..etc"`) then it shoud work. 

Would be nice to see a more complete code fragment.

Comment: using array.<select id="name[]">